# Facebook - Making the photos of a public page only available to followers

Tags: facebook, privacy, photo

I manage a facebook page for a local club and we obviously want to use it to share photos of events we've done.

I'm trying upload an album, is there a way I can protect the photos so only people who like the page can see them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your title you said "public page" and in your question you mentioned a "group". The answer to this would be different depending on if you are using a Facebook page, or a Facebook Group.

If you are using a Group format you should be able to restrict who can view your posts, so that group members can see them only.

However, if you are using a Fan Page format on Facebook I don't think you can restrict who can view them. I believe that all fan page content is public, and I don't think you can restrict this.